Why does Apache give me a 401 Unauthorized?
I've set up Apache on a Linux home computer. I've also added a Samba network share to that machine. In Apache's Sites-Enabled conf directory, I have added a virtual host for example.com (and added this record to my DNS). This VHost serves /var/www/sambaweb/*, which is a symlink to /media/samba/sambaweb/
Apache seems to work fine, I can get the default page on the servers IP address. However, when I enter the example.com URL, I get a 401 Unauthorized error.
Any idea why? And any idea if the reason for this 401 gets logged anywhere? I have checked Apache's Access- and Error logs, but only see the 401 in the access log and no errors.
Edit: Doesn't seem to be a rights-issue. I found this on another answer here:
sudo -u www-data ls -l /media/samba/sambaweb/

And it works fine for me. www-data can apparently see all the files no issue.
EDIT 2: Here's some conf-files
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com  

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /media/samba/sambaweb/example

    <Directory /media/samba/sambaweb/example >
        Options FollowSymlinks
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel info

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>


If it's not permissions-related, then IIRC, unless a specific log file has been defined in the virtual host, everything should be logged to /var/log/apache2/error.log

Can you edit your virtual host file into the question?

Also if you don't have a Require all granted directive in the virtual host definition, unless I'm mistaken, everyone will be denied access to the virtual host, so try adding Require all granted as well

@kos: Conf files added. I tried adding require all granted, but now Apache won't start: Require not allowed in <VirtualHost> context

Not sure if there's more to it, but allow from all has long been deprecated in favor of Require all granted, so try and change that line to Require all granted.

Where did you put it? It should be nested under the Directory directive, but in this case remove the allow from all directive as well

The first problem is that the allow from all directive has long been ignored by Apache; the "new" method of granting access to everyone is by using Require all granted; hence the allow from all directive in your virtual host definition isn't really granting access to everyone, and as overall access hasn't been explicitly granted / denied to any entity, Apache falls back to its default of denying access to everyone.
To address this you should change the allow from all line to
Require all granted


Adding to this: since you also want to auto-list the contents of the directory, you should also add
Options +Indexes

which, if missing, also would make Apache fail in case no DirectoryIndex directive is present (which seems like the case here, and rightfully so, since you don't want to serve a specific page).

Overall, your minimal virtual host configuration file should look like this:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /media/samba/sambaweb/example

    <Directory /media/samba/sambaweb/example>
        Require all granted
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


I think there is nothing wrong with your configuration. Just one directive missing.
DirectoryIndex index.html

Either you add DirectoryIndex or you have to specify the entire URL.
http://example.com/index.html
Here is a conf that works for me:
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /media/samba/sambaweb/example

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www.example.com-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www.example.com-access.log combined

HostnameLookups Off
UseCanonicalName Off
ServerSignature On

DirectoryIndex index.html

<Directory /media/samba/sambaweb/example>
   Options +Indexes
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +MultiViews
   AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

And finally, one should also check the permissions of the directory /media/samba/sambaweb/example and the files in it.

No - "If none of the resources exist and the Indexes option is set, the server will generate its own listing of the directory." - which is probably what OP wants to do.

You went above and beyond to provide an answer, which is great, however: please take 1 minute to read the link I posted on my previous comment :) DirectoryIndex has a default value of index.html, as outlined in the link I posted; that means that omitting a DirectoryIndex directive entirely (when using +Indexes) would do just the same as putting in a directive such as DirectoryIndex index.html. So that itself isn't useful, and probably works against OP's intentions of listing the directory's content.

Now try your configuration and replace Require all granted with allow from all, as in OP's config. What happens? :) The issue is that they're using an obsolete directive AND (I now notice) also missing +Indexes.
